# Custom data-attributes from select_tag not submitting - Rails 4

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple search form_tag in a Rails 4 app.

One of the options is a select_tag:

```
<%= select_tag "plottable[plottable_id]", options_for_select(Plottable.all.map{ |plottable| [ plottable, plottable.id, { 'plottbale-type' => plottable.class } ] }), prompt: 'Select one option'%>
```

The HTML is generated properly, resulting in:

```
<select name="plottable[plottable_id]" id="plottable_plottable_id">
  <option value="">Select one option</option>
  <option plottable-type="Pool" value="3">Pool1</option>
  <option plottable-type="Pool" value="4">Pool2</option>
  <option plottable-type="Asset" value="33">Asset1</option>
  <option plottable-type="Asset" value="34">Asset2</option>
</select>
```

When submitting the form the plottable-type does not get submitted. Here are the params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "from_time"=>"", "to_time"=>"", "plottable"=>{"plottable_id"=>"35"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you can not submit data attributes with form

Comment: if you want to send this params with form then just create a hidden field tag and submit by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

```
<select name="plottable[plottable_id]" id="plottable_plottable_id">
<option value="">Select one option</option>
  <option plottable-type="Pool" value="3">Pool1</option>
  <option plottable-type="Pool" value="4">Pool2</option>
  <option plottable-type="Asset" value="33">Asset1</option>
  <option plottable-type="Asset" value="34">Asset2</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name=plottable[type] value="", id="plottable_plottable_type">


$('#plottable_plottable_id').on('change', function(){
    var type = $('option:selected', this).attr('plottable-type');
  $('#plottable_plottable_type').val(type);
})
```

you can add hidden field tag by rails code as well

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "plottable[plottable_type]"%>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! With a bit tweaking of the selectors it worked!